# Activate tab in TabControl that was retrieved as AutomationElement

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation, tabcontrol, tabitem

I used the UIAutomationClient API to retrieve an AutomationElement `t`:

```
AutomationElement t = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(...);
```

The WPF counterpart of `t` is a `TabItem` inside a `TabControl`. I want to activate the tab that `t` represents (i.e. bring `t` into foreground). **How do I do that?**

I tried `t.SetFocus();`, but it did not have any (visible) effect at all.

If I had the `TabItem` (let's call it `tabItem`), I would just call

```
tabItem.IsSelected = true;
```

So I thought by using the select pattern I could achieve the same:

```
var p = t.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
p.Select();
```

It turned out that the `IsSelected` property of `p` already is `true` prior to selecting it - so calling `Select` still does not select/activate the tab. But in the GUI, the `TabItem` is clearly not selected/activated.

Comment: Try setting the SelectedIndex property.

Comment: How should I do that? I do not have the object as a TabControl; only as AutomationElement.

Comment: I think you must first SetFocus the TabControl first before you select specific TabItem. Please see my example below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, This is my solution below hope it helps even though it's already late.

**Example UI:**

[image: Example]

**Sample Code:**

```
 AutomationElement aeDesktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;
 AutomationElement aeForm = aeDesktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "davinceleecode"));
 AutomationElement aeTabControl = aeForm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "tabControl1"));
 aeTabControl.SetFocus();

 AutomationElement aeTabPage = aeTabControl.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "tabPage2"));    
 SelectionItemPattern changeTab_aeTabPage = aeTabPage.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;

 changeTab_aeTabPage.Select();
```

Please check the **`IsKeyboardFocusable`** properties and make sure this is set to **`true`**.

[image]